# Free UML Design Software

Tags: c#, uml

I have been doing UML diagrams on paper for awhile now, but I want to start doing it digitally for obvious reasons. I have used many bits of software that can do this, but some are over complicated and some just are not intuitive.

I should point out that I am a .Net programmer, so I don't use Eclipse :(

Can anyone suggest some good UML designers that are free? Online or desktop apps are fine.

Comment: You should change the title of the question to "Free UML Design Software" makes more sense.

Comment: Just `UMLET` http://umlet.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try [GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com), it is online.

Comment: Providing that the user is not an Eclipse User, this answer looks like the best one so far.

Comment: Probably the OP wants a bit of code generationm but nothing states he only wants class diagrams. This tool only has Class Diagrams and Use Case diagrams (experimental). No activity, no sequence, no state machine...

Comment: yeah this is suitable. I don't need code generation :)

Answer (score 2):

Having tried several ones, my choice would be Modelio, which is easy to handle and quite complete.

But it depends what exactly you want to do with it. Core Modelio is free, but some additionnal functionalities are not (I'm not exactly sure which ones, but I suppose code generation would be in the list **Edit :** Java generation is free but C# is not... sigh...).

Answer (score 1):

ArgoUML is old but still reliable and standalone: http://argouml.tigris.org/

You now have Eclipse UML plugins which are free: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

A good long list is available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

Which ones are good is beyond me though. I suggest trying them out and keep the one that is the easiest for you to use.

Comment: Yeah, I have been through that list before and I have installed/tried some of them but I was hoping that someone would know which are good rather than me looking for that elusive needle :(

Comment: Hi r3plica, do you have more objective requirements than just free? Because complicated and not intuitive are subjective/related to yours habits...
Do you want to be able to generate C#? export in XMI? Extend the tool in C#, Java, VisualBasic?

Answer (score 0):

UML Software as **bouml** are good,

but I recommand you **Eclipse + Ecore / Ecore diagram** technologies : You can draw your model and with acceleo generate code automatically.